# SWT - Autocomplete

Tags: java, swt

There is an autocomplete option for text box. 
First time - when the user types 2 characters it will fetch the values from an API method and it will suggest the autocomplete option. This is fine. but when delete the two characters and again if you type the first character it shows the old autocomplete option which is already fetched from API method. I dont want this. when the user type the second character it again fetches the values from API method and displays autocomplete option. So what i want is the autocomplete option should not be displayed until the second char is typed.

Comment: Show us the code you are using.

Comment: I cannot show the code(I am not authorized to show the code)...could you please give me some example where autocomplete option should be displayed only after the second char is typed.

Comment: At least tell us which classes you are using